# Formula with features: unity at zero, zero at inf and control over the shape

Tags: matlab, function, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting, mathematical-expressions

I would like to seek help in finding a formula for following shape and behavior with controllability over behavior. 
with following features: y=f(x)

1. y-> unity (or controllable constant) as x->0
2. y->0 as x->inf
3. Steep  fall after x=constant
4. Control over the average slope of the steep. for example, slope at y=0.5. (lover  priority)
5. Graph y=f(x) would be something like:

[image]

Thanks

SAM

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Post the code you have so far

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, a mirrored and shifted version of the logistic function might be what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: Great. Logistic function is a great one. I think I can play around with this to get what I want.